# ASP.NET 4 support for Rebus?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, rebus

So begins from 0.75.1, Rebus no longer supports ASP.NET 4?

My question will be:

1. Is 0.75 a stable release for .NET 4 project?
2. Are we going to continue get bug fixes (if any) for .NET 4 target project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 0.75 Rebus has targeted [.NET 4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4.5), which was a requirement to support the usage of `async`/`await` in the library.

I'm not an expert on ASP.NET and whether the version follow the versions of .NET, but Rebus will work as long as your host process targets (at least) version 4.5 of the framework. If ASP.NET 4 is only available for projects that target .NET 4, then that implies that you cannot use versions > 0.72 of Rebus.

And then an answer to your questions:

1. You should pick the latest version of Rebus, but that requires that you target (at least) .NET 4.5. If that is not an option, you should pick Rebus 0.72 (which is the last version available that targets .NET 4).
2. No (*)

As for the (*) above, I'd like to make the following fairly long and elaborate point: Generally, *you can't count on getting bug fixes* for the free, open-source software you have downloaded and are using, freely, without having paid a cent - at all!

If you want to be able to *reliably count on getting bug fixes* for your free software, I suggest you get a support contract with a company that is willing to provide that service. [My employer](http://www.d60.dk/) provides that service for Rebus in case you're interested.

With that said, I'll add that I am a pretty helpful person, and I do a lot for people to have a nice experience with Rebus, but I am sure that you can understand that I cannot promise to provide bug fixes for the old versions.

I will be around for helpful advice if you run into something, but - as I am developing Rebus mostly in my spare time - you can probably understand why I need to concentrate my efforts on the current version.

Comment: plus 1 for possibility of having paid support contract :) I would love to have one in future.

Comment: @mookid8000 If 0.75 targets .NET 4.5 why can we only use versions up to 0.72 and not versions < 0.75? Thanks.

Comment: I am seeing that up to 0.73 .NET 4.0 is targeted. After that it's .NET 4.5.

Comment: @MartijnB there was a problem with the build after the upgrade to .NET 4.5 - the 0.73.0, 0.74.0, and 0.74.1 versions are defective and are taken off the NuGet.org list.... therefore, 0.72.0 is the last version to support .NET 4, and 0.75.0 the first to require .NET 4.5

Comment: @mookid8000 thanks. Need a build for some .net 40 apps as well. Need to build from src here.